# REQ.BODY being passed as empty in GET call

Tags: mysql, reactjs, sequelize.js

I have the following code that I am having issues with.  I create an object in js and then do an API call passing that object to the controller.  The object is populated in the js component and in the API component, but it is empty when it gets to the controller.  I have verified that I have app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); coded in my server code as answers to other similar issues have recommended.

Snip of js/API call:

```
getGeoLocation = () => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            let latLng = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude,
                name: "current location",
                details: false,
                detailsText: null,
                markerIcon: currentLocation
            };
            let searchData = {
                currentLat: latLng.lat,
                currentLng: latLng.lng,
                dist: this.state.dist,
                limit: this.state.limit
            };
            console.log("in JS component:");
            console.log(searchData);

            API.getLocations(searchData)
                .then(res =>
                    this.setState({ markers: res.data }),
                    console.log("markers: "),
                    console.log(this.state.markers),
                    this.setState(prevState => ({
                        currentLatLng: latLng,
                        markers: [latLng, ...prevState.markers]
                    }))
                )
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            console.log(this.state.markers)
        });
```

Snip of API:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  // Gets all locations
  getLocations: function(searchData) {
    console.log("in API:");
    console.log(searchData);
    return axios.get("/api/locations/", searchData);
  },
```

Console log of above:

[image]

Snip of controller:

```
module.exports = {
findAll: function (req, res) {
    console.log("req.body in controller:");
    console.log(req.body);
    db.Locations
        .findAll({
            attributes: { include: [[sequelize.literal("(3959 * acos(cos(radians(" + req.body.currentLat + ")) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(" + req.body.currentLng + ")) + sin(radians(" + req.body.currentLat + ")) * sin(radians(lat))))"), 'distance']] },
            having:
                sequelize.where(sequelize.col('distance'),
                    { [Op.lte]: req.body.dist }
                ),
            order: sequelize.col('distance'),
            limit: req.body.limit
        })
        .then(dbModel =>
            res.json(dbModel))
        .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
},
```

Console log results:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `axios.get` second parameter is a config object and not a request body, see [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) and [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/787) github issue.
Although the `GET` request specification doesn't explicitly forbid sending a request body with a `GET` request, it should be avoided since there are many frameworks and libraries that will ignore it so you should pass the payload in the query string and not in the request body.